# How can I simulate a click on a Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use React refs in my code and the end goal is to simulate a click on selected refs (you will see how they are selected in my code).

I tried to use the method ".click()" on my element, but the console shows me `Uncaught TypeError: pinterest.click is not a function`

When I log the "pinterest" var in the loop, I get a "Component".
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import InterestBox from './InterestBox'
import Axios from 'axios'

export class InterestList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {pinterests: []}
        this.pinterestRefs = React.createRef()
        this.pinterestRefs.current = [];
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/interests')
        .then((success) => {
            this.setState({pinterests: success.data.data.interests});
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(prevProps));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))
        if(this.props.alreadyChecked != prevProps.alreadyChecked) {
            this.props.alreadyChecked.forEach((item) => {
                this.pinterestRefs.current.forEach((pinterest) => {
                    if(item == pinterest.props.id) {
                        console.log(pinterest)
                        pinterest.click();
                    }
                })
                console.log(item)
            })
        }
        console.log(this.pin)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {Object.keys(this.state.pinterests).map((interest, i) => {
                    var pinterest = this.state.pinterests[interest];
                    var callbackRef = node => this.pinterestRefs.current[i] = node;
                    return <InterestBox id={pinterest.id} onClick={this.props.onClick} icon={pinterest.picture_src} title={pinterest.name} ref={callbackRef} />
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestList
```

How can I simulate a click ?

Thank you !

PARENT CODE :

````
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '../../components/Button';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import ErrorContainer from '../../components/ErrorContainer';
import InterestList from '../../components/register/InterestList';

export class EditUser extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loading: true, interests: []}
        this.addInterest = this.addInterest.bind(this);
        this.logState = this.logState.bind(this);
    }

    addInterest(id, name) {
        var mid = 'm' + id;
        console.log(this.state.interests[mid] == undefined)

        if(this.state.interests[mid] == undefined) {
            console.log(this.state);
            this.setState((state) => {
                state.interests[mid] = name;
                return {interests: state.interests}
            })
        } else {
            console.log('deleted')
            var newInterest = this.state.interests;
            delete newInterest[mid]
            this.setState({interests: newInterest})
        }
        console.log(this.state.interests)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var token = Cookies.get('token');
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/details', {headers: {"Accept": 'application/json', "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}}).then(
            (success) => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    firstname : success.data.data.user.firstname, 
                    lastname: success.data.data.user.lastname, 
                    email: success.data.data.user.email,
                    dob: success.data.data.user.dob,
                    address: success.data.data.user.address,
                    uinterests: success.data.data.interests
                })
            }, (error) => {
                this.props.history.push('/deconnexion');
            }
        )
        var places = require('places.js');
        var placesAutocomplete = places({
        appId: "plZJLSHIW8M5",
        apiKey: "0eddd2fc93b5429f5012ee49bcf8807a",
        container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
        });
    }

    logState() {
        console.log(this.state);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Dashboard loading={this.state.loading}>
                <h1 className="title">Modifier mon profil</h1>
                <form className="user-form offer-update-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>Prénom :</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleChange}></input> <br />
                <label>Nom de famille :</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleChange}></input> <br />
                <label>Email :</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                <label>Adresse :</label>
                <input type="address" id="address-input" name="address" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                <label>Date de naissance :</label>
                <input type="date" name="dob" value={this.state.dob} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                <InterestList alreadyChecked={this.state.uinterests} onClick={this.addInterest} />
                <ErrorContainer errors={this.state.errors} />
                <Button type="primary">Soumettre les changements</Button>
                </form>
                <Button type="danger" onClick={this.logState} />
            </Dashboard>
        )
    }
}

export default EditUser

```

CHILDREN CODE :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export class InterestBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.images = require('../../img/interests/*.svg');

        this.state = {activated: false};
        this.interest_box_content = React.createRef();
        this.interest_text = React.createRef();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.props.handleClick(this.props.id, this.props.title);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            activated: !prevState.activated
        }))        
    }

    updateDimensions() {
        console.log((window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.interest_box_content).width))
        this.refs.interest_text = (window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.interest_box_content).width)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="column is-one-fifth-desktop is-half-touch">
                <div className="interest-box">
                    <div className="interest-box-adjuster">
                        <div ref={"interest_box_content"} className={"interest-box-content " + (this.state.activated == true ? 'interest-box-activated' : '')} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            <img className="interest-icon" src={this.images[this.props.icon]} style={{'height': '50%'}}></img>
                            <i className="activated-icon fas fa-check"></i>
                            <span ref={"interest_text"} className="interest-text">{this.props.title}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default InterestBox

```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHiPv.png
````

Comment: I think this is an xy problem. What do you want to happen when you simulate the click?

Comment: @JMadelaine In the InterestBox event handler, it will changes the appearance of the box and for the parent event handler, it will add the box id to an array in the state. I really just want to trigger these two functions. I will add the parent and children code to my question.

Comment: Then you should trigger those two functions directly. Create a function that does what you want, and call that function inside the onClick handler and also here. The button is not in charge of the functionality, it just initiates it. The functionality lives elsewhere.